# Почему у double и float ошибка накапливается не равномерно?

Tags: c++, c, float, double, числа-с-плавающей-точкой

### Может кто объяснить, почему ошибка накапливается не равномерно, а довольно странными скачками?

Сейчас я экспериментирую с накапливанием ошибки для `float` и `double`.

Я провожу вычисления по следующей формуле:
[image: Y_k=(Y_k/k)*k,Y_0=1,k=1,…n].

Вычисления проводятся циклично в течении определённого промежутка времени. Результат вывожу в текстовые два текстовых файла (один для `float`, другой для `double`). Код написан на C++, он приведен ниже. **Компилирую без оптимизации!**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <ctime> 

using namespace std;

int main() {
    float y = 1.0;
    double yd = 1.0;
    int k = 1;
    int end = 0;

    ofstream fout_float("output_float.txt");
    ofstream fout_double("output_double.txt");
    if (!fout_float.is_open() || !fout_double.is_open())
        return -1;
    fout_float.precision(64);
    fout_double.precision(64);

    while (end / CLOCKS_PER_SEC / 60 != 10) {
        float tmp_y = y;
        double tmp_yd = yd;
        
        if (k < INT_MAX / 10000) {
            y = (y / k) * k;
            yd = (yd / k) * k;
            k++;
        } else {
            k = 1;
        }
        
        end = clock();
        
        if (end % (CLOCKS_PER_SEC * 20) == 0) {
            cout << end / CLOCKS_PER_SEC << "s\n";
            fout_float << end / CLOCKS_PER_SEC / 60 << '\t' << 1 - y << '\t' << tmp_y - y << endl;
            fout_double << end / CLOCKS_PER_SEC / 60 << '\t' << 1 - yd << '\t' << tmp_yd - yd << endl;
        }
    }

    fout_float.close();
    fout_double.close();
    return 0;
}
```

Все бы хорошо, но я не особо понимаю, почему я получаю следующие результаты.

**У float.**

[image: график изменения ошибки float]

Как и ожидалось, ошибка есть, но почему она делает это странными скачками, я понять не могу.

Зачастую ошибка равна 0, иногда же она 5.9604644775390625e-08 или -5.9604644775390625e-08.

**У double**

[image: график изменения ошибки double]

Как и полагается, ошибка намного меньше. Но она продолжает так же скакать.

Ошибка бывает равна как 0, так и +-1.1102230246251565404236316680908203125e-16

Comment: А как она должна накапливаться?

Comment: тип float/double не может точно представлять любые числа. И его значение дискретно. Соответственно и результаты такие же дискретные.

Comment: Потому что она _накапливается_. UPD: Что-то я вообще не пойму, что в коде считается...

Comment: @Qwertiy, данный код написан с целью накаливания ошибки. В моей дипломной работе, результаты этого  эксперимента играют хоть не ключевую, но важную роль.

Answer (score 1):

Это всё деление.Его результат не получается вписать в эту переменную.Вот и всё.

| *float* | 0 | . | 00000000 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| результат деления | 0 | . | 09382892876 |

876 не получается вместить, и они удаляются.Вот и неточность деления.

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]

Answer (score 0):

Попробуем посчитать до 1000 с шагом 10 добавляя погрешность от -.5 до +.5 на каждом шаге:

```js
var noacc = 0, acc = 0

for (var q=1; q<=100; ++q) {
  var err = Math.random() - .5
  
  noacc = q*10 + err
  acc += 10 + err
  
  console.log(noacc.toFixed(3), acc.toFixed(3))
}

// Просто прокрутить вывод до низа
setTimeout(() => document.querySelector(".as-console-wrapper").scrollTop = 1e6)
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100vh }
```